# node module works but not if using npm link

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

---

I'm using a 3rd party library for a certain module in my project. I also want to contribute to the library as well so I used npm link so that my code changes would be easier to manage. When I tried to include the library normally via npm/node_modules the package is loaded successfully but when I moved it to another folder and used npm link it throws this error

```
ERROR in ../react-google-maps/lib/utils/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel'
```

Here's my package.json

```json
    {
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Logistics",
  "author": "wnoveno",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --port 9000",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.11.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.9.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.9.1",
    "react": "^15.0.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.9.12",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.29.5",
    "react-cookie": "^0.4.6",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-redux-loading-bar": "^2.0.2",
    "react-router": "^2.4.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-form": "^5.0.0",
    "redux-localstorage": "^0.4.0",
    "redux-persist": "^3.1.1",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^3.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
  }
}
```

and webpack.config

```json
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    },
      {
        test: /(\.scss|\.css)$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      }]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss'],
    modulesDirectories: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react-google-maps/lib'),

    ]
  },

  // resolveLoader: {
  //     modulesDirectories: [
  //         './node_modules/react-google-maps/node_modules/babel-cli'
  //     ]
  // },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  },
  externals: {
    'config': JSON.stringify(require('./config-dev.json'))
  },

}
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    },
      {
        test: /(\.scss|\.css)$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      }]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss'],
    modulesDirectories: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react-google-maps/lib'),

    ]
  },

  // resolveLoader: {
  //     modulesDirectories: [
  //         './node_modules/react-google-maps/node_modules/babel-cli'
  //     ]
  // },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  },
  externals: {
    'config': JSON.stringify(require('./config-dev.json'))
  },

}
```

here's the package's package.json

```json
{
  "name": "react-google-maps",
  "version": "5.0.0",
  "description": "React.js Google Maps integration component",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "files": [
    "lib/",
    "src/",
    "CHANGELOG.md"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf lib",
    "prebuild": "npm run lint && npm run clean",
    "build:watch": "npm run build -- --watch",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel src --out-dir lib",
    "lint": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test eslint .",
    "pretest:cov": "npm run lint",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test:cov": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/isparta cover --report lcov _mocha -- $npm_package_config_mocha",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha $npm_package_config_mocha",
    "prerelease": "npm run build && git add -A && git commit -m 'chore(lib): compile from src using babel'",
    "release": "standard-version"
  },
  "config": {
    "mocha": "--compilers js:babel-register ./src/**/__tests__/*.spec.js --require ./src/__tests__/setup.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "React.js",
    "React",
    "react-component",
    "google",
    "map",
    "maps",
    "place",
    "places",
    "googlemap",
    "googlemaps",
    "google-map",
    "google-maps",
    "google map",
    "google maps",
    "GoogleMapsMixin",
    "Map",
    "Marker",
    "Polyline",
    "Polygon",
    "Circle",
    "Directions",
    "InfoWindow",
    "SearchBox"
  ],
  "author": {
    "name": "tomchentw",
    "email": "developer@tomchentw.com",
    "url": "https://github.com/tomchentw"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-flow-comments": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-typecheck": "^3.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.5.2",
    "codeclimate-test-reporter": "^0.3.1",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.7",
    "eslint": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^9.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.8.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^1.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "expect": "^1.14.0",
    "isparta": "^4.0.0",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.2",
    "jsdom": "^9.2.1",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "standard-version": "^2.2.1",
    "tomchentw-npm-dev": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.9.2",
    "can-use-dom": "^0.1.0",
    "google-maps-infobox": "^1.1.13",
    "invariant": "^2.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "marker-clusterer-plus": "^2.1.4",
    "react-prop-types-element-of-type": "^2.1.0",
    "scriptjs": "^2.5.8",
    "warning": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try installing it separately in the other folder?

Comment: Yes npm install on the separate folder works ok. But webpack doesn't seem to recognize the loader if it's on a separate folder. This is my guess on why babel is not recognized.

Comment: Could you tell us *how* exactly you link?

Comment: I used npm link https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link. It created a symbolic link to the separate folder in the node modules instead of having the files directly under there. That's why it's weird since everything else is the same except for the (actual) location of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Your `resolve` configuration is incorrect, because webpack 1's `resolve` configuration is confusing...

`modulesDirectories` does not accept absolute paths (i.e. the things you're constructing with `path.resolve`), but only directory names. The default `modulesDirectories` will do the right thing.

What you need is a `fallback` pointing to `path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')` (Would just `path.resolve(__dirname)` work? I don't know).

When the `npm link`ed module itself requires another module, by the time the it tries to `resolve` a dependency, it's outside your project's folder, so it doesn't have access to your `node_modules` via node's normal resolve (what `modulesDirectories` implements). webpack's resolver will then try to look inside the `fallback` absolute path.